# Remove a list of object names

Tags: r

I have an array of object names `v <- c("v1", "v2")`, which associates with objects `v1`, `v2`.
How should I remove these objects using `rm()`?
I tried `rm(mget(v))`, but I got error:

```
Error in rm(mget(v)) : ... must contain names or character strings
```

Comment: `?rm` tells you how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joshua. rm(list=v) works.

Answer (score 8):

--Editing the answer based on better understanding of the problem as pointed out by Dason--

Since the intention is remove the objects referred to by the contents of v & not v itself, `rm(v)` (as was suggested earlier by me) is inappropriate (as it will remove v though not the objects pointed to by the contents of v (viz. v1 & v2).

```
> v1 <- "A"
> v2 <- "B"
> #v is a vector containing the references to v1 & v2 as character strings
> v <- c("v1","v2") 
> v
[1] "v1" "v2"
> rm(v)
> v
Error: object 'v' not found
> v1
[1] "A"
> v2
[1] "B"
>
```

The OP wishes to remove the objects v1 & v2 & not v. As Adam identified, the solution would be `rm(list=v)`

```
> rm(list=v)
> v
[1] "v1" "v2"
> v1
Error: object 'v1' not found
> v2
Error: object 'v2' not found
>
```

Comment: `rm(v)` would remove the character vector containing the names - not the objects themselves.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the clarification. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: That's your call.  You could delete it.  You could modify it so that your answer actually answers the question.  (AdamNYC gave an answer that works in the comments so you could just use that)