# How to remove a subset of the variables in a function's local environment in R?

Tags: r

Right before a function returns in `R`, I would like to remove all of the local variables **with the exception of one or two.**

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
f <- function(){
  keep_this_local_var <- 3
  remove_this_local_var <- 4
  rm(setdiff(ls(environment()), c("keep_local_var"))) # doesn't work
  return(ls(environment())) 
}
f() # should only be 3
```

Motivation: my "real life" `f` function calls `source()` several times. There will be a possibly large, random amount of variables generated by each `source()` call. I won't know the names of each variable in advance; however, I do have a short list of variable names I want to to **keep**. Similar code has worked for me in the past, but when I `source` to the `.GlobalEnv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
f <- function(){
  keep_this_local_var <- 3
  remove_this_local_var <- 4
  rm(
    list=setdiff(ls(environment()), "keep_this_local_var"),
    envir = environment()
    )
  return(ls(environment())) 
}
f() # should only be 3
```

As [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569087/remove-a-list-of-object-names) mentions, you need to specify `list=`.